# CodeIgniter: Error on retrieving a single result row

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day!

I have this code in getting an employee's information. (single result)

**controller**:

```
public function get_employee_info()
{
    $id = $this->input->post("id");

    $data["emp_default_info"] = $this->My_model->get_single_result("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = '$id' "); 

    $this->load->view("employee_info_view", $data);
}
```

**model**:

```
public function get_single_result($query_statement)
{
    $query = $this->ECS_DB->query($query_statement);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**view**:

```
foreach ($emp_default_info as $row)
{
    echo $id = $row->id;
    echo "<br/>".$lname = $row->lname;
    echo "<br/>".$fname = $row->fname;
    echo "<br/>".$mname = $row->mname;
}
```

**ERROR:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

All I want to do is to return the specific employee's info. I don't know why I got this error.

Any help please?

Thank you!

Comment: just now edited my answer so you can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

Controller :

```
public function get_employee_info() {
    $id = $this->input->post("id");

    $data["emp_default_info"] = $this->My_model->get_single_result($id);

    $this->load->view("employee_info_view", $data);
  }
```

Model :

```
public function get_single_result($id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $query = $this->db->get("employees");
    return $query->result();
}
```

View :

```
foreach ($emp_default_info as $row)
{
    echo $id = $row->id;
    echo "<br/>".$lname = $row->lname;
    echo "<br/>".$fname = $row->fname;
    echo "<br/>".$mname = $row->mname;
}
```

Comment: tried that sir, error gone but no result displayed. I checked my query and it's working.

Comment: can you print_r `$data["emp_default_info"]` and share results

Comment: @Jorz sorry bro bymistake i put my model name `welcome_model` but now i replace ,so now you can try again , copy controller and try

Comment: Getting result?

Comment: nah. it's still empty :(

Comment: Means on that `id` not exists ,so try with another `id ` that exists in the records

Comment: Thanks for the help sir.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
> ```

Its because `$emp_default_info` is either null or false or argument is not array

So what you can do is as follows:

**Either correct your model code :**

```
public function get_single_result($query_statement)
{
  $query = $this->ECS_DB->query($query_statement);
  $row = $query->row_array();
  if (isset($row)){
     return $row;
  }
      return array();
}
```

**OR**

**validate in view whether its array**

**Also `$emp_default_info` is array because you called `row_array();`, you can't access like `$row->id`**

```
if(is_array($emp_default_info) && !empty($emp_default_info))
{

   foreach ($emp_default_info as $row)
   {
    echo $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<br/>".$lname = $row['lname'];
    echo "<br/>".$fname = $row['fname'];
    echo "<br/>".$mname = $row['mname'];
   }

}else{
      echo "Employee Information not found";
}
```

**We can regenerate this error like this for example**

```
$ php -r 'foreach(null as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

/*false OR FALSE*/
$ php -r 'foreach(false as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

/* Not array */
$ php -r 'foreach("somestring" as $e){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mssql_result::array()

Answer (score 0):

`row_array()` returns array of results.

View:

```
    echo $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<br/>".$lname = $row['lname'];
    echo "<br/>".$fname = $row['fname'];
    echo "<br/>".$mname = $row['mname'];
```

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your code but nothing happens. Error still exists

Comment: Change id also as array

Comment: wrong, it returns array of specific row not array of rows

Comment: @JigarShah agree, yes it returns array I will change my answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not have use foreach as `row_array` returns array of specific row only. check [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) for further information

```
echo $id = $row['id'];
echo "<br/>".$lname = $row['lname'];
echo "<br/>".$fname = $row['fname'];
echo "<br/>".$mname = $row['mname'];
```

Comment: error gone, but no result displayed. I used if(isset($row)) instead of foreach()

Comment: if no result is there then you do not have result from query. please check that

Comment: what is o/p of `print_r($query->row_array())`

Answer (score 0):

Function `row_array` returns `The requested row or NULL if it doesn’t exist`.

So if your query fails `NULL` will be stored in `$data["emp_default_info"]`.

And you need to pass variable of type `array/object` to foreach, in your case it is might be `NULL`.Try your output query at database site(workbench or phpmyadmin) first.

If query success it will return a row(single row).So you can loop like

```
foreach($emp_default_info as $val)
{
    echo $val;
}
```

because it returns only one row you dont need to use a loop.you can access 
it by array index directly as `$emp_default_info['id']` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with minimum no. of lines.

```
public function get_employee_info()
{
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get('employees');
    $row = array_shift($q->result_array());
    echo $row['fname']; //and so on
}
```

So no need to add code for fetching one record in Model as you did. Its already there in parent model.